# Redelivering messages from dead letter channel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I can put the messages in dead letter queue if message re-delivery attempts fail.
How do I initiate re-delivery of archived messages in Dead Letter queue?
Does Camel provide any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DLQ is just another JMS destination.  Simply create an additional Camel route that is used to process messages from the DLQ.

Comment: And when the additional Camel route will kick off?

Comment: The DLQ JMS Destination and associated Camel Route are no different than any other route.  You can either make it a polling consumer that will execute at a predefined interval or event driven where the existence of any message will kick off the process.

I have to run to a meeting but will be back shortly if you have further questions.

Answer (score 2):

As @sully6768 suggested - you can use [Camel component](http://camel.apache.org/components.html) handling the Dead Message redelivery for you (like [JMS](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html)).

**However** you can also define how many times the message will be attempted to send before Camel moves it to the Dead Letter Queue (BTW you can also define the time interval between the redelivery attempts).

```
errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("jms:queue:dead"))
    .maximumRedeliveries(3).redeliveryDelay(5000));
```